# Знаки препинания

Tags: грамматика

Добрый день,
какие знаки препинания нужно ставить между числами если пишешь много чисел подряд?
Номер заявки: 444082 30.03.2015

Comment: @Eva, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Обычно пишут "Номер заявки: 444082 от 30.03.2015 г."